# env | grep $USER vs env | grep USER

Tags: environment-variables, grep

new to Ubuntu  was wondering if anyone can explain why one only shows the user and username and the other shows more information? what's the difference between $USER and USER

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the first form,

```
env | grep $USER
```

The variable `$USER` is expanded to its value for grep. So, `grep` will show all lines which contains the value of `$USER` variable. For me, the value of `$USER` is `anwar`. So the command is equivalent to `env | grep anwar`

If you want to grep the literal `$USER`, use single quote as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142729/grep-for-expression-containing-variable)

In the second form,

```
env | grep USER
```

only the literal `USER` is used for grepping and thus `grep` will only show those lines containing `USER`.